# Is there anything like !in_array()?

Tags: php

$file_name = "smith.jpg" // This gives error 'Invalid file extension'
What could be the problem?

```
$whitelist = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

// Validate file extension
    if(!in_array(end(explode('.', $file_name)), $whitelist))
        HandleError('Invalid file extension');
```

Comment: It works for me without any errors.

Comment: Why not be a bit more verbose and try to see what's going on?  Pull out `$parts = explode('.', $file_name); $ext = end($parts);` and take a look at them separately to see if everything's as you expect...

Comment: I can't generate the same error. Your example results in TRUE. Could you post more code?

Comment: @user247245, you should post it as answer, which can be accepted by the OP :)

Comment: Doesn't `end()` return a string? Why would you perform an `in_array` comparison to a single string? -- nevermind, looking for the needle. I omit my question. And yes, str_tolower is the answer. alternativly you could `preg_match('/^\.('.implode('|',$whitelist),'$/i',$file_name)`

Comment: Why do people always insist on substring() or explode() to extract a file extension rather than pathinfo(PATHINFO_EXTENSION)... and I agree with strtolower()

Comment: Hint: replacing `HandleError('Invalid file extension');` with `{ HandleError('Invalid file: ' . $file_name); }` will make your life sooo much easier.

Comment: This is what I have to remove invalid characters---$file_name = preg_replace('/[^'.$valid_chars_regex.']|\.+$/i', '', strtolower(basename($_FILES[$upload_name]['name'])));

Comment: It works if I remove the invalid character validation but I would like to remove invalid xters from the filename.

Comment: Something like: $file_name = preg_replace('![^a-zA-z0-9\.\-]!', '', $file_name); shouldn't impact anything else? Just put whatever you want to keep in that regexp (everything else will be removed).

Answer (score 4):

It would have been better if you used:

```
echo pathinfo('/www/htdocs/your_image.jpg', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

> use the right functions for what they are made for.

Answer (score 2):

It's a referencing error:

```
$whitelist = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

// Validate file extension
$parts = explode('.', $file_name);
if(!in_array(end($parts), $whitelist))
{
 HandleError('Invalid file extension');
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing that out. Strict standards forbid passing functions/expressions for arguments that requires a reference.

Comment: What is the solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Pls how can I treat period as a valid character in the following expression?----$file_name = preg_replace('/[^'.$valid_chars_regex.']|\.+$/i', '', strtolower(basename($_FILES[$upload_name]['name'])));

Comment: Use pathinfo as shown above, it's the best solution to your problem - I was simply pointing out the error. You really don't need a regexp here (esp not that one!).